# Groupon deals api work with limit parameter

Tags: groupon

I want to get top popular deals using group-on deals API. when we pass limit parameter with URL then how it works it gives top deals according to limit or randomly?

Answer (score 0):

Limit parameter will restrict your result count, that will not effect the deals sorting.